# Can someone offer a comparison (pros and cons) of the sites that one can play for real money on in the US?

Tags: nlhe, online

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Is it possible to play for real money online in the US?](https://poker.stackexchange.com/questions/722/is-it-possible-to-play-for-real-money-online-in-the-us)

I would like to play online for real money. I am a US resident. I understand that there are several sites where I can do this as Jeffery Blake points out here https://poker.stackexchange.com/a/730/773

What factors should I consider when I choose a site? What are the pros and cons of these sites? Which software should I use and does that depend on which site I pick?

Comment: The comparisons in the original "duplicate" are a good representation of the depth of comparison between sites you'll ever get. I'll close this question for that reason.