# Is it legal to play online poker in New Jersey? If so, is it worth it?

Tags: poker-history, poker-stars, gaming-law

If I move from NYC to NJ am I able to play online poker with real money?

I see this [old post](https://poker.stackexchange.com/questions/457/is-online-poker-legal-or-not-in-the-united-states), but it was asked in 2012 and last edited in 2017. I am asking again in 2019 with the recent changes in sports gambling. [This site](https://playinglegal.com/new-jersey) makes it sound like it is perfectly legal to play online in New Jersey.

> Players must be at least 21 years old to play for real money
>
> Players
> must be located within New Jersey state borders while they're playing
>
> Players do not need to be a resident of New Jersey
>
> Players can start
> and fund a user account from anywhere in the Country, but can't start
> playing for real money

This lines up with the NJ-dedicated [pokerstars site](http://www.pokerstarsnj.com/).

As a follow up question, if it is legal, *is it worth it*? I know this is subjective to a degree, but I am wondering about the level of competition and whether or not it can be quantified. Such as the profitability of top 15% of players vs. the heyday back in 2003 until the shutdowns.

Comment: I wont comment on the legality, but I'm confident in saying that you won't know if its worth it unless you try. Practice is all. Bankroll manage appropriately, and take a shot. It could be the best decision you ever made; I highly doubt it would be the worst. Good luck.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think you answered yourself at the first question, if it is legal. Yes, it is. Not only Pokerstars confirms it, but all other poker affiliates site say as well. And I don't think anybody would dare lying here.

If it's worth it, there is a whole other discussion. According to [this link](https://www.pokerscout.com/reviews/pokerstars-nj/), there were 211 players at most, in the last 24 hours, 95 average on the last 7 days. At the moment of writing this post, there were 26 cash game players online (I don't know how many tournament players). These stats are for you to interpret as well, but my opinion is that it isn't worth it, because there are too few players. Sure, you get history quicker against your fellow players, but they will do the same too, so it's a wash. Long term, you'll reach a level where you'll trade money back and pay the rake, as you move up in stakes.

I don't know the quality of the games, because I am from Romania, but judging by the numbers alone, my opinion it's that it's not worth it.